# Gradle publish multiple private jars to nexus

Tags: gradle, nexus

In my project lib folder, I have some proprietary jars, which I need to upload to nexus using Gradle.
Ex:

```
ibm1.jar
ibm2.jar
abc.jar
```

I would like to upload to nexus as `com.abc.ibm:ibm1.jar,com.abc.ibm:ibm2.jar` and `com.xym.abc:abc.jar`.

I could find some samples for uploading one, but not multiple where I can specify group name and artifact name.

Answer (score 0):

The group and version will be inherited from the project. So if you need different group and version I think you'll need a separate project for each.

See [Publishing Artifacts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html) and [ConfigurablePublishArtifact](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurablePublishArtifact.html)

Here's how you could publish the two jars in a single project (assuming project group and version ok)

```
group = 'foo'
version = '1.0'
artifacts {
    archives(file('lib/jar1.jar')) {
        name = 'ibm1'
        classifier = ?
        extension = ?
        type = ?
    }
    archives(file('lib/jar2.jar')) {
        name = 'ibm2'
        classifier = ?
        extension = ?
        type = ?
    }
}
```